# IntelliJ IDEA 13 + Tomcat 7 deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I try to deploy empty web application in IDEA on Tomcat7. Tomcat stops work on line:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\devel\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\manager
```

And no another actions to do. Tomcat is clear and throught cmd it runs ok.

Comment: What do you mean, empty?

Comment: hello world application

Comment: From this error message it looks like one of the default tomcat packages has failed to deploy correctly. I'd reinstall tomcat and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in JMX port, witch was default setting by IDEA to 1099, but in my CATALINA_OPTS this port was set to 8090, thats why tomcat starts up but can't deploy war from IDEA

Comment: The JMX port can be set at the `Edit Configuration` dialog on the `Server` tab.